# boost 1.55, vs 13 signal error number of arguments

Tags: c++, boost

Using boost 1.55 in Visual Studio the following code results in an error (after the code)

```
void foo(float a) {
    a *= 2;
}

int main() {
    boost::signals2::signal<void(float)> sig;
    boost::function<void(float)> f = boost::bind(foo, _1);
    sig.connect(f);
}
```

And the error: `1>...\dep\include\boost\bind\bind.hpp(192): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments`

I dont know, but i sort of am happy that its not a term taking 0 arguments as that would pretty much contradict the idea of the signal. Whats going on here?

Comment: How did you define your signal?

Comment: Oh shoot, forgot to include that line. Edited into my posting.

Comment: Note that void foo(float a) does not do anything since you pass a by value instead of float& a. Did you define using namespace std::placeholders;?

Comment: The problem is, that signal somehow wants to have a callable with 0 arguments even if it must take an argument. Changing `foo` to `void foo()` and sig to `signal<void ()>` and f to `function<void ()>` and `bind` to `bind(foo)` everything is fine. But as soon as the signal expects a parameter things stop working. Fun fact: I can also pass a function without arguments to sig.connect if the signal has parameters. `_1` is taken from boost, not `std::placeholders`. Im aware, that it has no effect, its just for testing.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong whatsoever with a signal that takes no arguments. Look at the "hello world" signal example in Boost tutorial.

Comment: Yes, but according to my signature `signal<void (float)>` the idea behind the signal is to take an argument. Thats why its contradicting the idea of the signal.

Comment: Bind is rather useless here. Try passing foo directly to connect.

Comment: It doesn't contradict the general idea, it is just not compatible with your particular signal.

Comment: This is an example to reproduce the error, in the real world example bind is needed. However passing foo directly to connect there are various other errors:
error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace'', 
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type', 
error C2208: 'boost::_bi::type' : no members defined using this type

Comment: Try this: `boost::function<void(float)> f = foo;` If this doesn't work, your compiler is probably broken.

Comment: Back to `term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments`, which is indisputably true, but it must not evaluate to such a function. The compiler pretty sure aint broken, I guess its just another bug of boost with VS 13.

Comment: "The compiler pretty sure aint broken" -- that's a bold statement if I ever heard one.

Comment: Yea, and I stay by it, you might wanna use it as a quote in a signature?

Answer (score 0):

I could compile and run the following code with boost 1.53 and VS2012..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

void foo(float& a) {
    a *= 2;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::signals2::signal<void(float)> sig;
    boost::function<void(float)> f = boost::bind(foo, _1);
    sig.connect(f);
    float i = 5;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    sig( i );
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    std::cin >> i;

    return 0;
}
```

Result 5, 10 , 5. I couldn't really explain why it isn't 5, 10, 10...

Comment: Yes, it works with boost 1.53 and vs 2012, but im using 1.55 and visual studio 2013. Its not under known bugs with VS13 so i assume it has to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for boost 1.55 and visual studio 13:

```
void foo(float a) {
    a *= 2;
}

int main() {
    boost::signals2::signal<void(float)> sig;
    sig.connect(boost::signals2::signal<void (float)>::slot_type(foo, _1));
}
```